# Spring security ignoring my authenticationEntryPoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jersey-2.0

I recently upgraded to Spring Boot 2.1.7 and Spring security 5.1.6 and for some reason Spring Security ignores my configured exception handling for handling HTTP 403 responses. It keeps on redirecting to /error resulting in an HTTP 404 error since this page doesn't exist. My Spring Security configuration looks like this:

```
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .addFilter(headerAuthenticationFilter)
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .hasAnyRole("ROLE1", "ROLE2")
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that with the newer Spring Boot version an extra exclusion needs to be added. This is a snippet of the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

The part that I had to add was ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class. Before this wasn't necessary.